# How to write code to refresh table inside jquery-ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#ajax1').click(function () {
     var adMessagev = $('#adMessage').val();
     var datastr = 'adMessage=' + adMessagev;                    
     $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          data: datastr,
          url: "adminchatServlet",
          success: function ()
          {                                                     
              $('#tb1').dataTable().ajax.reload();
          }
     });
    });
 });
```

Comment: step 1: learn the difference between Java and JavaScript

Comment: So what is your exact question? What kind of problem did you encounter? And what frameworks or libraries do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you calling another function,

```
function func1() {
   $.ajax({ ... }).done(func2);
}
```

And,

```
function func2(){
  $.ajax({ ... });
}
```

Hope this helps.